# Initializing many object member variables in initializer list

Tags: c++, design-patterns, builder

I've a question regarding best practices in initializing many object members in one class. Background of this question is an embedded project where I'm frequently using references and constructor injection:

```
class ComponentA 
{
public:
   ComponentA(SomeComponent1& dependency1, SomeComponent2& dependeny2)

private:
   /* ... */
};
```

Now imagine I've many other Classes like ComponentA and they have to be instantiated in one class:

```
class Layer
{
private:
  ComponentA componentA; // Composition
  /* ...and many other components */

public:
  Layer(SomeComponent1& firstDepOfA, SomeComponent2& secondDepOfA, ...) : 
       componentA(firstDepOfA, secondDepOfA), /* other components */
};
```

I was thinking of the builder pattern to reduce the complexity:

```
class Layer
{
private:
  ComponentA componentA; // Composition
  /* ...and many other components */

  /* now private */
  Layer(SomeComponent1& firstDepOfA, SomeComponent2& secondDepOfA, ...) : 
       componentA(firstDepOfA, secondDepOfA), /* other components */

public:
  ComponentAIntf& getComponentA ( ... ); 

  class Builder
  {
  private:
    SomeComponent1* firstDepOfA;
    SomeComponent2* secondDepOfA;
    /* other dependencies/constructor parameters */

  public:
    /* returns Builder, because we want a fluent api */
    Builder& setFirstDepOfA(SomeComponent1* dep) {firstDepOfA = dep; return *this;}
    Builder& setSecondDepOfA(SomeComponent2* dep) {secondDepOfA = dep; return *this;}

    Layer& build()
    {
       /* check parameters */
       ... 

       /* create instance, constructor will be called once when scope is entered */
       static Layer layer(/* parameters */);
       return layer;
    }
  }
};
```

A major drawback of the builder class is that the constructor parameters of the member instances are duplicated. 
I think this can be also achieved with templates, but I haven't found any resources. An example would be nice, but I wanted to avoid using templates. Any help is appreciated. I think I'm missing something...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Builder pattern here would be dangerous, because it would be possible for you to call `build` before all of the dependencies have been set. (One of the reasons to use constructor injection is to *prevent* the class from being instantiated without explicitly specifying all of its dependencies.)

You should inject `ComponentA` into `Layer`, rather than let it create its dependency directly. For example:

```
class Layer
{
private:
    ComponentA& componentA; // Composition
    /* ...and many other components */

public:
    Layer(ComponentA& componentA, ...) : 
        componentA(componentA), /* other components */
};
```

When using dependency injection, you should ultimately have a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) where you actually build your object graph. (This is where all of the dependency injection actually occurs.)

If you need to instantiate `ComponentA` on demand, then you can consider delegating the responsibility to a factory:

```
class ComponentFactory
{
private:
    SomeComponent1* firstDepOfA;
    SomeComponent2* secondDepOfA;
    /* other dependencies/constructor parameters */

public:
    ComponentFactory(SomeComponent1* firstDepOfA, SomeComponent2* secondDepOfA, ...) :
        firstDepOfA(firstDepOfA), secondDepOfA(secondDepOfA), ...
    {
    }

    ComponentA CreateComponentA()
    {
        return ComponentA(firstDepOfA, secondDepOfA);
    }

    ...
};

class Layer
{
private:
    ComponentFactory& componentFactory; // Composition
    /* ...and many other components */

public:
    Layer(ComponentFactory& componentFactory, ...) : 
        componentFactory(componentFactory), /* other components */

    void DoSomethingThatUsesComponentA()
    {
        ComponentA = componentFactory.CreateComponentA();
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. The build() method in my example would check all parameters and throw an error if there are any inconsistencies (I forgot the constructor of the builder class which would set all pointers to NULL).
As far as I understand the link, my composition root would be the main() method where I would instantiate ALL components...

Comment: @pr0d1g1 Yeah, that would make sense for the build method to check that all parameters have been set; but that check is performed at run-time (whereas constructor injection allows you to perform this check at compile-time). And you're correct about the composition root being your `main` (or as close as possible to it - like being created by a factory, which is created in the composition root).